# I want oposite seed in my list how can I solve it

Tags: python, random, seed

for example I have this list:

```
lst = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

and I shuffle it for example with seed = 42:

```
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(lst)
```

I took this list after shuffle:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

I want to take oposite of this shuffle too
How can I take this list:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

I want oposite seed

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to produce the opposite list, or how to derive the random seed(s) that _would_ give you the desired output? The first is trivial, the second is a degree in cryptography for anything other than a toy example

Comment: lst = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
with seed(42)
I recieved this:
[[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
now I want to know with which seed I can take this:
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
this is oposite of shuffled lst with seed 42